# What exactly did Yoda die of?

Tags: star-wars

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What happened to Yoda?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4288/what-happened-to-yoda)

I'm curious - What exactly what Yoda died of? I apologize in advance if there's an obvious answer here but the way he phrased things to Luke gave me pause:

> YODA (tickled, chuckles) I do, yes, I do! Sick have I become. Old and
>   weak. (Points a crooked finger) When nine hundred years old you reach,
>   look as good you will not. Hmm?
>
> Yoda chuckles at this, coughs, and hobbles over toward his bed.
>
> YODA Soon will I rest. Yes, forever sleep. Earned it, I have.

I've always assumed that it was old age but he explicitly says "**Sick** have I become".

Comment: Luke disappointed him by leaving his training early. Thus, Yoda died of a broken heart, just like Padme.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With old age can come sickness (or be identified as sickness in and of itself). But, like you quoted, Yoda did not elaborate on his condition other than that he was very old and in poor health. It's likely the rough living conditions of the Dagobah swamp probably wasn't good for his health, nor were the rigors of Luke's training.

Comment: No one has died of old age [since 1951](http://maggiesfarm.anotherdotcom.com/archives/11364-Not-one-American-has-died-of-old-age-since-1951.html)

Comment: True, but "Natural Causes" is considered a legitimate cause of death. In any case, this is the star wars universe. Our laws don't apply :p

Comment: @SSumner Yoda died a long, long time before 1951 :)

Comment: Good points. My bad

Comment: No one dies of old age - it's always a heart attack, stroke, organ failure, cancer. Medicine takes all the fun out of life.

Comment: Not like Yoda grammar, I had to read this twice to make sure of.